# Accessing data sent in json form from server in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm working with ajax calls and am having trouble retrieving and using the data sent by the server.
From the server, I'm sending this:

```
$details["name"]=$name;
$details["cat"]=$category;
$details["price"]=$price;
$details["quant"]=$quantity;
$details["img"]=$image_url;
echo json_encode($details);
```

This is the ajax call on the client-side:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'update.php',
    data: {data:id},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        var x=JSON.parse(data);
        alert(x);
    }
});
```

I want to be able to access $details["name"] and so on but when I do alert(data) in ajax success function, it alerts the correct info i.e {"name":"xyz","cat":3...} . However, when I do alert(x), it displays [object Object]. If I access x["name"], it says undefined.
Can anyone point out the problem?

Comment: x.name maybe ? I Think it does the trick

Comment: Thanks @Flo. You're right, it does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After parsing your response *JSON string* will become a *JavaScript Object.*

In your case, the alert displays Object because you are including the whole Object name.

To get the desired value of a property, you will have to use `ObjectName.PropertyName`, In your case `x.name`

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3m6439b/)** for your better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON more directly....
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
$.getJSON({
    type:'post',
    url:'update.php',
    data: {data:id},
    success: function(details){
        console.log(details, details.name);
    }
});
```

Try that.  Data should be already parsed into JSON.

Also, instead of `alert`, i've used `console.log`, which is the pro way to go.  Well worth learning.